# Как добавить отступы между кнопками при создании из кода в Android?

Tags: android, android-button, margin

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(this);
        gridLayout.setRowCount(5);
        gridLayout.setColumnCount(7);
    setContentView(gridLayout);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
        layoutParams.setMargins(10,10,10,10);

    for(int i=1;i<31;i++) {
        Button button = new Button(this);
            button.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            button.setTextSize(18);
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
        gridLayout.addView(button,layoutParams);
    }


}
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: попробуйте свойством margin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146781/decorating-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-to-display-divider-between-item